# Pipe vs Subscribe in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, subscribe

I hope everyone just doing fine. Can, please someone clearly explains which one to choose among **pipe** and **subscribe**, and why? when it comes to not only getting the response but also to initialize some other variables or make changes to the boolean variables.

**Also have a look at the code. Is it the right way to do it?**

```
public getAlbums(){
    this.enableLoader = false;
    this.albumHttpService.getAlbums()
        .pipe(
            map((response) => {
                this.enableLoader = false;
                if (!response.albums.length) {
                    this.noDataSet = true;
                    if (response.albums === null) {
                        this.list = [];
                    }
                }
                else{
                    this.noDataSet = false;
                    this.list = response.albums;
                }
            }),
            catchError((error) => {
                this.noDataSet = false;
                this.data = [];
                throw new Error(error);
            }) 
        )
        .subscribe();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are totally different from each other, its like comparing oranges and apples. `pipe` allows you to chain multiple rxjs operators while `subscribe` as the name suggests retrieves data from an observable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within `pipe` you can concatenate many other functions and use these functions to write some logic, prepare the data for the view and etc.

`subscribe` is like the last point, where you get ready data and it is better not to write any logic there, just only assignments to your viewmodels or etc.

Comment: Thank you. here's a quick question, if I am getting you right then the above code snippet is fine and the logic goes to the pipe function. right?

Comment: @unknownuser Yes, it is good. But also you need to consider a fact, that you call an extra function. So if you have many items it can delay you

Comment: @SurenSrapyan could you explain *why* logic in `pipe` is better? What is the benefit? Why not directly subscribe to the original observable and alter + assign everything there?

Answer (score 22):

`Pipe` basically takes the output of the function and gives it as input to another function. It is a really great and efficient way to manipulate data and it is really powerful.

We are basically piping the output of something into a different function that can modify the incoming data or just to extra logic on top of the data (trigger side effects).

We can have multiple logics chained in the `pipe` operator.

`Subscribe` is called on an observable to subscribe to the final data that is pushed out from the observable.

Quick Example:
I have an observable which sends a string "World".

```
worldObservable$.pipe(
  tap(data=>console.log(data)), // Prints "World"
  map(data=> `Hello ${data}`)
)
.subscribe(data=>console.log(data)); // Prints "Hello World"
```

In this example, first I use `tap` to get the data and then log it.
Next, I modify the data using the `map` operator which changes the initial data.
When I then subscribe it logs the modified data, instead of the initial data.

I hope it gave you some more clarity.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the significant words in this answer are "side effects". If all you want to do is get the information from your observable, you subscribe to it, if you want to manipulate it on its way to that subscription (side effects), you insert a pipe and use any of the operator functions that allows. Sound about right?

Comment: This short worked example with its brief explanation is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for cheers